# TeamCity output missing javascript files compiled by Typescript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, teamcity

We use MSBuild to build MVC application which works after deployment.

But we want to switch to Team City and we have a problem with typescript files. The build server does not contain javascript files which should be result of **TypeScriptCompile** build action. We get following error when running the build:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182, 5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Scripts\Common\arrayhelpers.js" because it was not found.*

Does anybody have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: When you look on the server can you find the built file, but in the wrong place?

Maybe set up a simple TeamCity config and project with just one .ts file and see if you can get it working without the rest of the project and other steps in the way.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. You was right. Files was on the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Compiled js files was on the wrong place. We changed tsconfig.json file and now it works.